# Merge or redirect [fso] tag into [filesystemobject]

Tags: feature-request, tags, synonym-request

I was just about to write the wiki for the [fso] tag, but then I realized there already was a [filesystemobject] tag too. These two are the same and used for the same thing: the "Object Model component on Windows systems that represents the local file system."

Is there a way to redirect the [fso] tag to the [filesystemobject] one? The first one is the common abbreviation for the latter, so simply deleting the tag is not the best option IMO.

[fso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fso) 63 questions

[filesystemobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystemobject) 206 questions

Comment: The master would be filesystemobject, right?

Comment: @rene yes, that would be the master

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, I gave up after manually checking around 30 questions. All were using [FSO] as a synonym for [FileSystemObject]. Searching SO for "[FSO] flash" gave me the 3 results you have already found. Sooo... I suggest [FSO] get redirected to [FileSystemObject]. Does that mean that the wiki is shared between them, or should I go copy-paste? :) Also, if this happens, the [fso] tag must be removed from the mentioned 3 questions - replaced with the [Shared-objects] tag (it is missing on some. I'll add them now, but they will have to be peer reviewed).

Comment: If it's synonymized, one of them will cease existing as a separate tag, and thus the tag-wiki with it. (Edited the three questions I found.)